# Arkham Horror 2nd Edition: Can I sneak past a monster that moved to my investigator's location?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-2ndedition, monster-movement, encounters, movement

If my investigator is stationary and a monster moves to his/her location through some random effect can I still try to evade it or do I go to the horror check immediately?

Comment: I think that answered it perfectly. Can you post as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The rules for Phase III: Arkham Encounters states:

> Note that the card may indicate that “a monster appears,” in which
> case the investigator must either evade the monster (see “Evading
> Monsters,” page 14) or fight it (see “Combat,” pages 14-16).

Since you have the option to evade it, you don't do have to do the horror check immediately.

Under the Other rules area, you have this about the evade option

> Sometimes monsters appear as the result of a location or gate
> encounter. An investigator can evade these monsters just like any
> others. However, these monsters never remain on the board after the
> encounter is resolved. If an investigator evades such a monster,
> immediately return the marker to the monster cup.